# Sequelize not returning expected result with nested model includes, limit, and '$nested.column$' syntax

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Users are able to follow other users and niches. I want to return the most recent posts to a user based on what they followed.

I am getting the below error while using nested column syntax and having a limit on the query. I am also looking for the DB to return all niches that are connected to the post but it only returns the matched niche. The DB returns the query when I remove the limit but the niche matching issue persists.

I had the same issue with the user model but that was because i was using `'$users.id$'` instead of `'$user.id$'`.

I believe this issue is either with the nested portion of the niche call or how I am going about the Op.or/Op.in.

I do not understand where the proper naming convention comes from for the `'$nested.column$'` syntax but I tried:

`'$niche.id$'`
`'$niches.id$'`
`'$postsNiche.id$'`
`'$postsNiches.id$'`

I am sure I am struggling because of the M:N relationship between Post and Niche models.

For the response of only matched niches I have tried adding required: false but that does not give a change.

MYSQL Error:

```
"code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
"errno": 1054,
"sqlState": "42S22",
"sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'niche.id' in 'where clause'",
```

Query Function:

```
`exports.getPostsByUserIdFollowed = (req, res, next) => {
    UsersFollow.findAll({
        where: {
            userId: req.params.userId,
        },
        order: [
            ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
        ],
        attributes: ['followId','type']
    })
    .then(data => {
        let nicheIds = [];
        let userIds = [];
        for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
            switch ( data[i].type ) {
                case 'niche':
                    nicheIds.push(data[i].followId);
                    break;
                case 'user':
                    userIds.push(data[i].followId);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return Post.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { 
                        '$user.id$': userIds,
                    },{
                        [Op.or]: [
                            {'$niches.id$': nicheIds},
                            {'$niches.parentId$': nicheIds},
                            {'$niches.grandParentId$': nicheIds},
                        ], 
                    }
                ], 
            },
            include: [{
                model: User,
                attributes: ['id','name', 'username', 'profileImg'],
                include: [{
                    model: UserBlock,
                    separate: true,
                    attributes: ['userId', 'blockId', 'type'],
                }],
            },{
                model: Niche,
                attributes: ['name', 'id', 'parentId', 'parentName', 'grandParentId', 'grandParentName'],
            }],
            order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
            ],
            limit: 10,

        })
    })
    .then(response => {
        return res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    });
}`
```

Post Model File:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Post extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Post.belongsTo(models.user);
      Post.belongsToMany(models.niche, {
        through: 'postsNiche', 
        foreignKey: 'postId',
      });
    }
  };
  Post.init({
    text: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    imgUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    isProfileImg: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    isCoverImg: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    isSponsored: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    lat: DataTypes.STRING,
    lng: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'post',
    paranoid: true
  });
  return Post;
};
```

User Model File:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      User.hasMany(models.post, {
        foreignKey: 'userId'
      });
    }
  };
  User.init({
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    profileImg: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: process.env.MEDIA_ROOT + 'profile/profile.jpg',
      // TODO: Check functionality
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user',
    paranoid: true
  });
  return User;
};
```

Niche Model File:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Niche extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Niche.belongsToMany(models.user,{
        through: 'usersFollow', 
        foreignKey: 'followId',
      });
      Niche.hasMany(models.usersFollow, {
        foreignKey: 'followId'
      });
      Niche.belongsToMany(models.user,{
        through: 'usersBlock', 
        foreignKey: 'blockId',
      });
      Niche.belongsToMany(models.post,{
        through: 'postsNiche', 
        foreignKey: 'nicheId',
      });
    }
  };
  Niche.init({
    name:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    parentId:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    parentName:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    grandParentId:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    grandParentName:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'niche',
    paranoid: true
  });
  return Niche;
};
```

postsNiche Model File:

```
'use strict';
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class PostsNiche extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      PostsNiche.belongsTo(models.post, {foreignKey: 'postId'});
      PostsNiche.belongsTo(models.niche, {foreignKey: 'nicheId'});
    }
  };
  PostsNiche.init({
    postId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false
    },
    nicheId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'postsNiche',
    paranoid: true,
  });
  return PostsNiche;
};
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": 11680,
    "text": "If we learn to open our hearts, anyone, including the people who drive us crazy, can be our teacher. -Pema Chodron",
    "imgUrl": "https://picsum.photos/id/643/550/300",
    "isProfileImg": false,
    "isCoverImg": false,
    "isSponsored": false,
    "lat": null,
    "lng": null,
    "createdAt": "2023-07-13T17:14:57.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-13T19:14:53.000Z",
    "deletedAt": null,
    "userId": 87,
    "user": {
        "id": 87,
        "name": "Joanna Holmes",
        "username": "joaholmes",
        "profileImg": "https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=9",
        "usersBlocks": []
    },
    "niches": [ // Expecting all niche not just queried ones 
        {
            "name": "Chocolate",
            "id": 279,
            "parentId": 65,
            "parentName": "Food",
            "grandParentId": 6,
            "grandParentName": "Food & Drink",
            "postsNiche": {
                "postId": 11680,
                "nicheId": 279,
                "createdAt": "2023-07-13T19:15:13.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-07-13T19:15:13.000Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "reviews": []
},
```